# I want to change the string to datetime but it says OutOfBoundsDatetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to change the string to datetime but it says 'OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1010-08-28 00:00:00' and in my dataframe doesn't has '1010-08-28' data, It works to other columns but not this column. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: is this a valid datetime for you? if not and this happens when converting string to datetime with pd.to_datetime, set `errors='coerce'` to ignore it - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: @MrFuppes Is it correct? I do this " pd.to_datetime(data['Start Date'],format= '%m/%d/%Y' ,errors='coerce').dt.time " then all of my data are  00:00:00

Comment: yes, that is to be expected since your input doesn't seem to have time information. pandas does not keep date and time separately, so if you do not provide time, it will default to 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're using to convert your date, but I've found dateutil.parser to work really good for all formats.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

newDate = parse("1010-08-28")
print(newDate)
```

Then you can easily manipulate the date variable with the datetime module to use as needed.